# модуль mouse не кликает на лкм в ubuntu

Tags: python, мышь

и так, есть библиотека [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) в ней есть mouse.double_click(button='left') но оно не работает на ubuntu, тоесть запускаю я python файл с sudo, но не кликает

```
import mouse as ms
import keyboard as k
from time import sleep


while True:
    if ms.is_pressed(button = 'left') and not k.is_pressed("shift"):
        clicked = 0
        while True:
            sleep(0.01)
            ms.double_click(button="left")

            clicked+=1
            print(f"{w} ckicked!")

            if not ms.is_pressed(button = 'left'):
                break
```

Comment: if ms.is_pressed(button = 'left')  ?????

Comment: ну я сделал import mouse as ms @Эникейщик

Comment: в плане, если кнопка left зажата, то он кликает, если отжата то не кликает

Comment: А как же можно кликнуть, если кнопка зажата?

Comment: щяс попробую убрать

Comment: нет, не работает, убрал но он не кликает @Эникейщик

Comment: А текст печатает?

Comment: +++++++++++++++++

Comment: а движение ( https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#mouse.move ) работает?

Comment: @Эникейщик щяс посмотрю

Comment: @Эникейщик да, работает

Comment: тогда и нажиматься должно. Как определяется нажалось или нет? В том смысле. что если я просто кликну мышкой на пустом месте экрана, то ничего и не произойдет.

Comment: umh, я поставлю задержку в 1 секунду каждый клик @Эникейщик

Comment: вот видео, посмотрите https://imgur.com/a/pMeZgac @Эникейщик

Comment: ну что за проблема? @Эникейщик

Comment: да кто его знает... А right_click() или просто click() работает?